# How to Disable Auto-Hyphenation

Tags: ios, pages, spellcheck

I have had an iPhone 7 Plus since 2018. It is running on iOS 15.5 with Pages Document version 11.1.  Today, for the first time ever, after finishing one Pages Document with no issues, it suddenly started hyphenating words at the end of sentences.

The only help I can find is older information, nothing newer than two (2) years ago.

I have two screenshots that I could share, but I cannot find a way to attach.

Thanks,
FnuLnu

Answer (score 1):

As of yet, one can't turn hyphenation on or off in a Pages document in iOS, iPadOS, and iCloud.

If that has come out as an issue in a specific Pages document, you need to open the document with Pages on macOS and turn the hyphenation off (or on) via the Hyphenation option in the Document > Document sidebar options as also described in the "[Format hyphens, dashes, and quotation marks in Pages on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/format-hyphens-dashes-and-quotation-marks-tanad45f9cce/12.0/mac/1.0)" Apple support webpage.